# Replace contents inside HTML tags which is in String object

Tags: java

I've to replace contents for "href" inside all anchor tags. 
The whole HTML body is received inside a String object.

There are multiple occurrences of the tag anchor. I've to replace the value of "href" inside all anchor tags.

```
Parent.java {
  ...
  String htmlBody;
}
```

Example:

```
htmlBody="
<HTML>
<head>...</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr><td>
          <table>
            <tr><td>
                <a href="https://www.test.com/shop/s111/product/pro1"><img     src="..."></a>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <a href="https://www.test.com/shop/os222/product/pro2"><img src="..."></a>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    ...
</body>
</HTML>";
```

Please note each href value inside anchor tag is slightly different.

I want to know the best way to achieve this in Java.

Comment: Use a HTML parser like JSoup.

Comment: Yes, or simply a regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution doesn't check the validity of the input HTML, and assumes the URL is double-quoted:

```
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"([^\"]*)\">");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlBody);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String url = replaceUrl(matcher.group(1));
        matcher.appendReplacement(buf, "<a href=\"" + url + "\">");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buf);
    System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Comment: This is brittle; breaks if there are any attributes before or after the `href=`, or if the HTML is broken across 2 lines.  DO NOT USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML. It is the wrong tool for the job.  You would not use a chainsaw for brain surgery, [Required reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157)

Comment: @JimGarrison or rather a scalpel to take down a tree ;)